# Calculate image edited percentage in Java

Tags: java, image, percentage

How to calculate the percentage of an image (jpeg) that has been edited using Java? For example, when an image is uploaded, the user wants to know how many percent of that image has been edited, so if it is 0% it shows that it is an original picture.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. How for instance are you editing the image?

Comment: Create a method `double compute(BufferedImage image)` that computes the percentage. (If this answer is not sufficient, consider elaborating your question)

Comment: are you talking about image compression?

Comment: Do you mean while uploading or doing some operation on an image?

Comment: sorry if the question is unclear. basically i want to create a program  in Java that helps to calculate the percentage of an image. the percentage which shows how much of the photo is edited. is this clearer?

Comment: R u asking how to see if the image is photoshopped or not?

Comment: I'm still completely baffled. Try putting more information into your question, typing out a paragraph or two explaining things in greater detail. A little effort can go a long way.

Comment: He's asking how to measure how similar 2 images are.

Answer (score 1):

If the original image and the edited image haven't changed size this is trivial.  Compare every pixel in your original image to the edited image.  Those pixels which are not the same may have been edited.  The amount of change is `ChangedPixels / TotalPixels`.

Some image formats are lossy (JPG for instance.)  Because the format is lossy, saving an image with no edits, and comparing it against the original copy will likely measure some change when there were no human edits because some content was distorted.

Images with different sizes are easy too. Just compare as many pixels as possible (ie. the minimum of the widths, and minimum of heights.)  The amount of change then is:

```
int maxPixels = Max(width1, width2) * Max(height1, height2);
double amountDifferent = totalChangedPixels / (double)maxPixels;
```

Any pixels which were added or removed are considered "changed" pixels.